# Include different homepages dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, html, get, php-include

I have created template with multiple sections or segments, so for example i have navbar.php, homepage.php, about-us.php, contact.php... And basically whole website is cut in parts and on index.php i just have includes, like 
include('navbar.php'), include('homepage.php'). Also i have different homepages like slider-homepage.php, image-homepage.php, video-background-homepage.php... So what i need is ability to dynamically include these different HOMEPAGES with navigation links. So if i click on slider-homepage link i want it to grab and include slider-homepage.php part and put it on index and the rest of includes always stay the same. Is this possible or i need to create different php file for each of these homepages.

index.php

```
include('home_main.php');
//include('home_text_slider.php');
//include('home_text_typer.php');
//include('home_video_background.php');
//include('home_video_background_slider.php');
include('about.php');
//include('split-section-two.php');
include('split-section-video.php');
include('services.php'); 
include('parallax-a.php');
```

navbar.php

```
<li><a href="#">Home Main</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home Text Slider</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home Text Typer</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home Video Background</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home Video Background Slider</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough I do not recommend this kind of implementation of programming a website, you could do the following

Add a variabele to your links like:

`<li><a href="index.php?page=slider">Home Text Slider</a></li>`

In your index.php

```
switch($_GET['page'])
{
   default:
   case 'homepage':
     include('home_main.php');
     break;

   case 'slider':
     include('home_text_slider.php');
     break;
}
```

Comment: And what would you recommend?

Comment: I would use at least a more structured way of implementing that. A simple model view controller set up would do. What you did is not wrong but it becomes very fast unclear if you plan to increase the number of links and functionality.

Comment: Just tried it and it works great. Also i have no idea what is simple model view controller set up. Could you provide me some links so i can read about it.

Comment: Just before i choose any link in my navbar i get undefined index: error on index.php on line 5 where this code begins. And when i choose some link error disappear. Do you maybe know why is this happening?

Comment: Yea if isset fixed it :) I am such a noob. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this dynamically. Suppose when you click on slider then you can pass a value(using GET method) from the page like "slider-homepage", "home", "about" etc or any other types of value. Then you can manipulate your page according to your passed value.

```
  $page = $GET['page'];

  include $page.".php";
```

or, you can do this even by setting some logic like:

```
    if($page == "slider"){
      include $value.".php";
    }elseif($page == "home"){
      include "home.".php";
    }
```